# Multiple Domain Controller Environment. How to authenticate to only one Domain Controller

Tags: windows, domain-controller

At my job we have (Quantity: 5) different Windows Domain Controller (DC) where our hosts and servers systems are bound to AD and where our users authenticate with their AD credentials.

I have a specific Windows Server system running SolarWind Network Application and we are having some strange issue with users AD authentication.

After troubleshooting, chatting and talking with the SolarWind Networking Team, they recommend me to have the Windows Server where the SolarWind Application live, to just authenticate to only 1 Domain Controller and not to all 5 of them.

Question,
how do I adjust the settings where I can tell a system to only authenticate to a specific Domain Controller (DC) and not to all of them?

So far, I tried to edit the hosts file but no luck, traffic still coming through and I tried to create a custom rule firewall but no luck, traffic still coming through.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways that you can address this, but IMO the fastest way is to block outbound traffic with the windows firewall to the IP addresses belonging to the four DCs  you don't want to authenticate to.

Other alternatives are changing HOSTS entries on the local machine, or setting sites / priority for Active Directory as a whole.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I google how to Firewall block Ip Address and how to block using Hosts file.  I am still not sure how to do sites priority but I will find out.  I will talk to my boss first if I can do the hosts file, I think it is the most better approach in the way that I do not distrust some stuff.  I will get back here and let you know.